# Execution trace/flow in java 6 and higher

Tags: java, trace

I am looking for a tool that allows me to get the complete execution trace of a Java program. That is, I need the list of method invocations, in order, of my program.

I have found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171174/tracing-order-of-execution-in-java) where the OP talks about [Trace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/trace.html), which does exactly what I need, but it seems to be available only in java 1.5 and below.

Is there something similar for java 6 and higher?

Comment: You could have a look at [BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace). Cheers,

Comment: Looks interesting, but I'd prefer somegthing that doesn't imply adding more code. I'll use BTrace if I can't find anything else.