# How to trace Java servlet execution?

Tags: java, servlets, trace

I've hit one of those bugs that only seem to show up in production. Whenever I try to reproduce the error on my development machine, even with the same input data, I draw a blank.

So, I want to be able to trace the entire execution flow of this Java servlet which is running through Tomcat 7, from its invocation to the final exception that gets thrown. Ideally, it'd give me a lengthy list of method calls, parameters and return values. *Something like the *nix strace,* except for Java classes.

I did find [Execution trace/flow in java 6 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14706742/486504) where in the comments [BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace) is linked to. I've had a look at it, but don't really see how it might help me. Also, it looks to be centered around running through a separate Java program. I'm OK with adding a bit of code, but really don't want to have to go into every method to add a trace call.

The absolute best would be if whatever approach used to do this can be coaxed into logging through slf4j (since I already use that for logging), but any logging is better than none.

How to obtain such a trace of a servlet?

Comment: This question should be directed to the concrete implementation of a servlet container, i.e. "How to trace servlet execution in [Tomcat/Jetty/you name it]".

Comment: @MaDa Good point. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an automatic tool for this but it is fairly easy to do by hand.

Just pick a few relevant places (for example inside the servlet) when it is actually called and do something like:

```
logger.info("Called X with Params "+y, new Exception());
```

That will give you the method, the parameters and the stack trace.

Scatter a few more log lines like that in relevant places and you should be able to track down the problem.

Comment: Good idea. However, you should probably mostly log as DEBUG, at least when you include stacktraces.

Comment: I would never leave statements like this inside the program (generating and throwing away exceptions isn't cheap) so putting them at info level makes sure they will get removed rather than just turned off.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking about too if I can't find any better way to do it. However, I was hoping that there would be a more automated way. Throwing in an exception to get a stack trace at the point of the log entry is an interesting twist, though.

Comment: Don't throw the exception, just generate it! :D

Comment: I said "throwing *in* an exception" -- I did notice that you're only creating the exception object instance, not throwing it! However, not having tried it, I'd expect the logger to grab the call stack from it and put it into the log alongside the message.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It doesn't care where the exception came from or whether it has been thrown or not so creating an exception is a handy way to grab a stack trace at an arbitrary point in time.

Comment: I'll have to give Chasmo's and your suggestion a try, but I'm not sure I'll be able to do it right away. (And I'm still hoping for a more automated solution to get a complete call listing much like you get from strace.) In the meantime at least, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Mapped Diagnostic Context](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) can help you in this situation. Since you're using slf4j, it should be no problem to switch to logback as logging framework.

With it, you can provide additional informations, such as URI, session etc. + you can extend your logging pattern to include [method and class](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#method) to drill down your stack.

Comment: That last might actually provide a bit of a clue as to where the error occurs. I'll have to give both this and Tim B's suggestion a try, but I'm not sure I'll be able to do it immediately. In the meantime, thank you; I'll get back to this!